# Rails includes returning limited relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search page where users can search events based on tags.

I have the following method that is returned a list of events based on tag id's that are being passed to the method:

```
  def self.tagged_with_id(taglist)
    # convert taglist to an array if ids
    taglist = taglist.chomp.split(',').map { |x| x.to_i }
    #get tag name from each id
    normalizedlist = taglist.collect{|id| Tag.find(id).name}
    Event.includes([:tags]).where("tags.name IN (#{normalizedlist.map{|tagname| "'#{tagname}'"}.join(',')})")
  end
```

...and here is the view that is displaying the events...

```
<%- @events.each do |event| -%>
...
      <td><div class="tag-wrapper"><%= display_tags(event.tags) %></div></td>
...
```

Works like a charm, and does exactly what I need it to do (mostly). However, one issue I am having is in the view when `event.tags` is being displayed, only searched for tag is being displayed. I want all tags for each event to be displayed in the search results that are returned.

Just for context if I query an event with the tagged_with_id method, then view tags I get this...

```
2.1.5 :007 > e=Event.tagged_with_id('44').first
2.1.5 :008 > e.tags
 => [#<Tag id: 44, name: "winning"]
```

Here is the same event using rails find method...

```
2.1.5 :009 > e=Event.find 80
2.1.5 :010 > e.tags
 => [#<Tag id: 44, name: "winning">, #<Tag id: 91, name: "air">, #<Tag id: 114, name: "management">
```

I would like my tagged_with_id method to return Events with all tags included, not just the searched tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a solution but first, let's clean up that method of yours. First, you're finding tags one at a time, let's find them in one query:

```
normalizedlist = Tag.where(id: taglist).pluck :name
```

That does the same thing but all in one query, much faster.

Then let's clean up the last query:

```
Event.includes(:tags).where tags: { name: normalizedlist }
```

That also does the same as you had before but it uses the cleaner hash syntax for matching conditions on relations, also you don't need to `join` the list. ActiveRecord knows that when it gets an array as a value that you want to do an `IN`.

Finally, the solution, because that last query only loads the events with the selected tags, you'll need to reload the `event` object so that it loads all of its `tags` from the db:

```
display_tags(event.reload.tags)
```

That will load all the tags for that event.